# ui-grid row update

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Hello everyone i am beginner to "angularjs 1.x" and i want to update ui-grid row on change of textbox of that grid row without making any server call. can i reload that grid?

Answer (score 0):

for updating the row in db you need server call , but there is no need to have a server call for refreshing the grid as far as you have the updated value in the textbox , only setting the gridoption.data[x] to new value will fix the problem :)